# MEAN app deplouy to heroku error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to deploy a node.js app to heroku.

Everything seems to go well untill I try to open in the app through heroku with

```
heroku open
```

I then get

```
Opening nameless-taiga-6317... done
```

but I get an application error on my browser and heroku logs spits this out:

```
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:25.562616+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:27.685099+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `npm start`
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:29.513842+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:29.513866+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.256436+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.257127+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.255876+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.256743+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! node v0.12.5
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.257367+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.257575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! missing script: start
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.257725+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.257836+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.257951+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.263537+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.263763+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:30.264024+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:31.030724+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2015-06-29T20:56:31.048838+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[33m2015-06-29T21:01:55.665028+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Scale to web=1 by david.shave@gmail.com
←[32m2015-06-29T21:02:35.497433+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nameless-taiga-6317.herokuapp.com 
...
```

this is some of my server.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

....

```
//connect database

if (env === 'development') {
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/multivision');
} else {

mongoose.connect('mongodb://amp3rsand:multivision@ds039550.mongolab.com:39550/multivision');
}
```

....

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error...'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('multivision db opened');
});
```

...

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.listen(port);
```

I am running through a tutorial but not getting any help from the author so am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently missing an npm start script -- Heroku doesn't know HOW to run your application. You have two options:

Define a start script in your `package.json` file, or you could create a `Procfile` that tells Heroku how to run your app.

Here's an example:

```
# Procfile
web: node index.js # Tell Heroku what command to use to run your app.
```